# How do I remove an UIImageView animation from memory completely?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to free up my apps memory and want to completely remove loadingImageView from memory when I tap a button. How do I do this?

```
-(IBAction)animationOneStart { 

NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:88];

for(int count = 1; count <= 88; count++)
{
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testPic1_%03d.jpg", count];
    UIImage  *frame    = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
    [images addObject:frame];
}

loadingImageView.animationImages = images;

loadingImageView.animationDuration = 5;
loadingImageView.animationRepeatCount = 1; //Repeats indefinitely

[loadingImageView startAnimating];
[images release];

}

-(IBAction)removeFromMemory {

//What do I add here?

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `loadingImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; //Repeats indefinitely`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. If you want to remove UIImageView animation try this:

```
-(IBAction)removeFromMemory {
    [loadingImageView stopAnimating];    //here animation stops
    [loadingImageView removeFromSuperview];    // here view removes from view hierarchy
    [loadingImageView release]; loadingImageView = nil;    //clean memory  
}
```

---

For remove CoreAnimation from UIView instance use method:

```
[view.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

Comment: Don't forget to add `QuartzCore` framework and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`