# How to start and stop image animation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

How can I start and stop image animation using button control?

```
imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: 
[UIImage imageNamed:@"p1.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"p2.jpg"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"p3.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"p4.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"p5.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"p6.jpg"], nil]; 

imageView.animationDuration = 1.00; //1 second
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; //infinite

[imageView startAnimating]; //start the animation
```

Comment: -1. Use search - [How do I remove an UIImageView animation from memory completely?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7750378/194544). I have been answering this question for 5 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add two buttons using Interface Builder, create two `IBAction` methods in your controller, connect `Touch Up Inside` events with the IBActions.
Use `[imageView startAnimating]` to start, `[imageView stopAnimating]` to stop.