# iOS - UIImageView animation memory leak?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, memory, uiimageview

I am currently using a `UIImageView` to animate a series of images depending on a button pressed by the user. I have about 5 different sets of images, that i have created in `NSArrays`, such as this:

```
-(void)initiateAnimations {

punchani = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0001.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0002.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0003.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0004.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0005.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0006.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0007.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0008.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0009.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0010.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0011.png"],
           [UIImage imageNamed:@"punch0012.png"],nil];
}
```

And then i am using the standard animation code to loop them once:

```
player.animationImages = punchani;
player.animationDuration = 0.50;
player.animationRepeatCount = 1;
[player startAnimating];
```

However, as i load more and more/different images into the `UIImageView`, i eventually get an output that a Memory warning as follows: (subsituted my actual executable with 'appname')

```
 2013-03-15 20:52:23.065 AppName[2080:907] Received memory warning.
```

I knew this would probably happen, but ARC forbids me from releasing the arrays. How can i fix this leak? thanks

Comment: Note that each image will be full expanded to memory when used within UIImageView. To calculate the memory needed per image, multiply width by height by 4 (RGB+A).

Comment: By the way, you don't need to explicitly set up an array like this since your images are well named you can use the `animatedImageNamed:duration:` method, which I assume loads the images on demand instead of all at once.

Answer (score 4):

UIImage imageNamed: caches the images and will release the memory on it's own schedule. Use
    `+ (UIImage *)imageWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path`  to load memory directly

[Try this answer as well.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7750427/1357774) Remove array of images when animation is over

Comment: Thanks for this. I hate asking this, but how would i go about using it? I am struggling to find how to apply this...

Comment: `[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:yourBundlePath],....., nil];`

Comment: Just to expand on @DivineDesert 's anser, [UIImage imageNamed: ] uses the phone's cache to store the image. You don't have control of when iOS disposes of the cache, and if you only need to load the image one-time in memory, [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:] makes more sense and will be released immediately when not needed.

Comment: I try to create nsmutablearray like  `NSMutableArray *arrAnimatedImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];for (int i = 0; i<directoryItems.count; i++) { [arrAnimatedImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:yourBundlePath(i)]]; }`

but app crash reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil' Please help me how can i create NSMutableArray @DivineDesert